# How to add member with name into group from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-groups-api

I want to add members to Google group using `AdminDirectory.Members.insert`.

This is my code:

```
function addGroupMember() {  
  var member = {
          name: {
              givenName: 'Jhon',
              familyName: 'Doe'
          },
          email: 'mail@example.com',
          role: 'MEMBER'
      };
  var newMember=AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, 'group_email@example.com');
}
```

The members is created into Group Members of Google Workspace, but without name, as you can see below:

[image]

There is one way to change `Member` by `John Doe`?

NOTE: The email domain is external, is not the same of the organization.

Comment: Create a use first, in this step you can define their name, `AdminDirectory.Users.insert`. After that, assign the member to Group.

Comment: @hoangdv the members are from external domains: `@gmail.com, @hotmail.com, @yahoo.com, @any-domain.com` (see Note at end of question).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a deeper look at the documentation.

From the [`Member` overview](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members):

> A Google Groups member can be a user or another group.

Also you can see that the `Member` resource has no attribute `name` so it's indeed impossible to assign it a name before creating the `User` resource.

What you can do right now is creating an [`User`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users) through the [`users.insert`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/insert) request. After that store the `id` of said user and insert it into a group with [`members.insert`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/insert).

---

And of course if you have already created a bunch of users without specifying the names you can [update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update) them.

Comment: Ok, but the member's email i want insert are external, they aren't users of the domain. It's a distribution list for users with email adresses from `@gmail.com, @hotmail.com, @yahoo.com, @any-domain.com` ... I suppose is not possible to do that with external domain members?

Comment: Can't you just add the external mail in the `primaryEmail` of `users.insert`? Does it give you an error

Comment: I can't. I'm trying [this method `addUser`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_user) and i'm having the error: *Domain not found*. If I change the `@example.com`  by `@my-domain.com` the code works but it creates one user into Google Workspace, but not into the group. Then, I think is not possible to add name or lastname to members from another domain.

Comment: It seems that this is not possible right now. You could add it maybe in the other `email` field. If you really need this maybe you could try to file a *Feature Request* in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui).